# Antlr 4 parsing large c file takes forever

Tags: c, performance, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have a large c-code file (>9000 LoC) and attempt to parse it using this grammar:

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4

I waited for over an hour before aborting. The machine is a Core 2 Duo L9400 with 4GB of ram. Maximum java vm-heap-size is set to 2GB.
It does not produce any parse errors, but it simply doesn't finish.

After doing some research, I set the prediction mode to SLL, which produces a 
"no viable alternative at input" within seconds.

Next, I set the prediction mode to LL_EXACT_AMBIG_DETECTION and attached a  DiagnosticErrorListener to the parser. This produces a lot of "Ambiguity reports", mainly
concerning declarations/declaration-specifiers. I assume this forces the parser to backtrack extremely often, which I is probably the explaination for the long parsing time?

Is there anything I can do to improve performance other than attempting to rewrite the grammar?

Any help is appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's important to note that ANTLR 4 *never* backtracks during parsing.

The grammar you are referring to is not SLL, which prevents you from using ANTLR 4 in its fastest mode. However, during or experiments we were able to identify a single rule which we altered to make the grammar SLL. You may be able to obtain the altered grammar via the antlr-interest mailing list. I'm at a concert now so I don't have access to it.

Comment: I'm a little embarrased to admit it, but I can't find the antlr 4 interest mailing list. Could you please point me in the right direction, or maybe even to the grammar? http://antlr.org/support.html only refers to the archive of the antlr 3 mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  we converted that from the spec with only a single rule change is a demonstration that you could do it. We will optimize that one soon.