# ANTLR4 performance issue

Tags: antlr4

There has been some discussion on the performance of ANTL4 parsing e.g:

- [Antlr 4 parsing large c file takes forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311864/antlr-4-parsing-large-c-file-takes-forever)
- [Is there any good ways to improve the parser's performance generated using antlr4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645754/is-there-any-good-ways-to-improve-the-parsers-performance-generated-using-antlr)

and there is an open bug report:

- https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/994

that calls for using two phase strategy to improve the performance of ANTLR4. To do so you first call the parser in SLL mode and only on failure the slower LL mode is used.

This works nicely for small grammars like the one used in issue 994:

```
grammar expr;

expr: ID
    | 'not' expr
    | expr 'and' expr
    | expr 'or' expr
    | expr 'between' expr 'and' expr
    ;

ID: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
WS: [ \t\n\r\f]+ -> skip;
ERROR: .;
```

but if the grammar gets slightly more complicated and ambiguous:

```
/**
 * see https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/994
 */
grammar numexpr;

numexpr: if_statement EOF;

if_statement:
  if_part ( else_part ) ? 'endif';

if_part:
  'if' expr statement_list|
  'if' expr;

else_part:
  'else' statement_list |
  'else';

statement_list:
  statement +;  


statement: if_statement; 

expr: ID
    | VALUE
    | 'not' expr
    | expr '=' expr
    | expr 'and' expr
    | expr 'or' expr
    | expr 'between' expr 'and' expr
    ;

VALUE: [0-9]+;
ID: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
WS: [ \t\n\r\f]+ -> skip;
ERROR: .;
```

Using the two phase strategy doesn't work anymore. 
The timing result is:

```
  2    27 msecs   0,2
  3    95 msecs   3,5
  4    99 msecs   1,0
  5    64 msecs   0,6
  6    87 msecs   1,4
  7   181 msecs   2,1
  8   350 msecs   1,9
  9   822 msecs   2,3
 10  2912 msecs   3,5
 11  7134 msecs   2,4
 12 21420 msecs   3,0
ratio: 2,01
```

It takes more than double the time for each "and valuex=x" expression part being added starting with the input

```
if Value=0  and not Value0=0 and not Value1=1 endif.
```

There needs to be some work on the grammar to make it fit for SLL.

**How would this be done?**

- [How do I diagnose ambiguities in my ANTLR4 grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441249/how-do-i-diagnose-ambiguities-in-my-antlr4-grammar)

asks a related questions. So if I add

```java
if (mode.equals(PredictionMode.LL_EXACT_AMBIG_DETECTION)) {
  parserHolder.parser.addErrorListener(new DiagnosticErrorListener());
}
```

and change the doTestParser line to:

```java
doTestParser(parserHolder, PredictionMode.LL_EXACT_AMBIG_DETECTION, PredictionMode.LL);
```

I also do not get any ambiguity lines but only:

```
if Value=0  and not Value0=0 and not Value1=1 endif
line 1:20 reportAttemptingFullContext d=6 (expr), input='andnotValue0'
line 1:12 reportContextSensitivity d=6 (expr), input='and'
line 1:37 reportAttemptingFullContext d=6 (expr), input='andnotValue1'
line 1:29 reportContextSensitivity d=6 (expr), input='and'
```

Please find below a JUnit Test that shows the problem. It consists of two classes - an abstract base class and the test class that shows the timing issues with

- https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/994
  and
- https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1232

**JUnit Testcase**

```java
package com.bitplan.ruleparser;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.bitplan.expr.exprLexer;
import com.bitplan.expr.exprParser;
import com.bitplan.numexpr.numexprLexer;
import com.bitplan.numexpr.numexprParser;

/**
 * Test the Issue 994 performance
 * 
 * @author wf
 *
 */
public class TestIssue994 extends TestTwoPhaseParser {

  public static class ExprParserHolderFactory extends ParserHolderFactory {

    @Override
    ParserHolder getParserHolder(int index) throws Exception {
      return new ExprParserHolder(index);
    }

  }

  /**
   * 
   * @author wf
   *
   */
  public static class ExprParserHolder extends ParserHolder {

    public ExprParserHolder(int index) throws IOException {
      super(index);
    }

    private exprParser mParser;

    @Override
    protected org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser getParser(CommonTokenStream tokens) {
      mParser = new exprParser(tokens);
      return mParser;
    }

    @Override
    protected Lexer getLexer(ANTLRInputStream in) {
      return new exprLexer(in);
    }

    @Override
    protected ParserRuleContext parse() {
      return mParser.expr();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getInput(int index) {
      String andClause = "not X0";
      for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 1) {
          andClause += " or X" + i;
        } else {
          andClause += " and not X" + i;
        }
      }
      return andClause;
    }
  }

  public static class NumExprParserHolderFactory extends ParserHolderFactory {

    @Override
    ParserHolder getParserHolder(int index) throws Exception {
      return new NumExprParserHolder(index);
    }

  }

  /**
   * 
   * @author wf
   *
   */
  public static class NumExprParserHolder extends ParserHolder {

    public NumExprParserHolder(int index) throws IOException {
      super(index);
    }

    private numexprParser mParser;

    @Override
    protected org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser getParser(CommonTokenStream tokens) {
      mParser = new numexprParser(tokens);
      return mParser;
    }

    @Override
    protected Lexer getLexer(ANTLRInputStream in) {
      return new numexprLexer(in);
    }

    @Override
    protected ParserRuleContext parse() {
      return mParser.numexpr();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getInput(int index) {
      String andClause = "if Value=0 ";
      for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
          andClause += " and not Value" + i+"="+i;
      }
      andClause+=" endif";
      return andClause;
    }
  }


  /**
   * see https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/994
   * 
   * @throws Exception
   */
  @Test
  public void testIssue994() throws Exception {
    super.testDuration(new ExprParserHolderFactory(),60);
  }

  /**
   * see https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/994
   * 
   * @throws Exception
   */
  @Test
  public void testIssue994NumExpr() throws Exception {
    debug=true;
    super.testDuration(new NumExprParserHolderFactory(),12);
  }

}
```

**Base class**

```java
package com.bitplan.ruleparser;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.BailErrorStrategy;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.RecognitionException;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.PredictionMode;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.ParseCancellationException;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser;

/**
 * 
 * @author wf
 *         see https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/994
 */
public abstract class TestTwoPhaseParser {
  static boolean debug = false;

  public static abstract class ParserHolderFactory {
    abstract ParserHolder getParserHolder(int index) throws Exception;
  }

  /**
   * hold a parser and some input;
   */
  public static abstract class ParserHolder {
    ANTLRInputStream in;
    CommonTokenStream tokens;
    Parser parser;
    private Lexer lexer;
    private String input;

    /**
     * create a parser Holder for the given index
     * 
     * @param index
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public ParserHolder(int index) throws IOException {
      input = getInput(index);
      init(input);
    }

    /**
     * create a parser holder for the given input
     * 
     * @param input
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void init(String input) throws IOException {
      if (debug)
        System.out.println(input);
      in = streamForText(input);
      lexer = getLexer(in);
      CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
      parser = getParser(tokens);
    }

    /**
     * get an input of the given index/size
     * 
     * @param index
     * @return a string to be tested
     */
    protected abstract String getInput(int index);

    protected abstract Parser getParser(CommonTokenStream tokens);

    protected abstract Lexer getLexer(ANTLRInputStream in);

    protected abstract ParserRuleContext parse();

    /**
     * get the ANTLRInputStream for the given text
     * 
     * @param text
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static ANTLRInputStream streamForText(String text)
        throws IOException {
      InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
          text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      ANTLRInputStream in = new ANTLRInputStream(stream);
      return in;
    }
  }

  /**
   * test how long the parsing takes
   * 
   * @param parserHolderFactory
   * @throws Exception
   */
  public void testDuration(ParserHolderFactory parserHolderFactory, int max)
      throws Exception {
    long prevduration = 0;
    double ratiosum = 0;
    int ratiocount = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      ParserHolder parserHolder = parserHolderFactory.getParserHolder(i);
      doTestParser(parserHolder, PredictionMode.SLL, PredictionMode.LL);
      long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long duration = stop - start;
      if (duration < 1)
        duration = 1;
      if (i >= 2) {
        double ratio = duration * 1.0 / (prevduration * 1.0);
        System.out.println(String.format("%3d %5d msecs %5.1f", i, duration,
            ratio));
        ratiosum += ratio;
        ratiocount++;
      }
      prevduration = duration;
    }
    double averageRatio = ratiosum / ratiocount;
    System.out.println(String.format("ratio: %3.2f", averageRatio));
    assertTrue("Performance issue https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/994",
        averageRatio < 1.2);

  }

  /**
   * tes the parser
   * 
   * @param parserHolder
   * @param mode
   * @param fallBackMode
   * @return
   * @throws IOException
   */
  protected ParserRuleContext doTestParser(ParserHolder parserHolder,
      PredictionMode mode, PredictionMode fallBackMode) throws IOException {
    ParserRuleContext result;
    try {
      BailErrorStrategy errorHandler = new BailErrorStrategy();
      parserHolder.parser.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
      // set PredictionMode
      parserHolder.parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(mode);
      result = parserHolder.parse();
    } catch (Throwable th) {
      if (th instanceof ParseCancellationException) {
        ParseCancellationException pce = (ParseCancellationException) th;
        if (pce.getCause() instanceof RecognitionException) {
          RecognitionException re = (RecognitionException) pce.getCause();
          ParserRuleContext context = (ParserRuleContext) re.getCtx();
          throw context.exception;
        }
      }
      if (fallBackMode != null) {
        parserHolder.tokens.reset();
        parserHolder.parser.reset();
        parserHolder.parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(fallBackMode);
        result = parserHolder.parse();
      } else {
        throw th;
      }
    }
    if (debug) {
      System.out.println(result.toStringTree());
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

**Debug output**

```
if Value=0  and not Value0=0 and not Value1=1 endif
([] ([14] ([17 14] if ([28 17 14] ([12 28 17 14] ([12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 28 17 14] Value) = ([52 12 12 28 17 14] 0)) and ([55 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 28 17 14] Value0)) = ([52 55 12 28 17 14] 0))) and ([55 28 17 14] ([12 55 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 28 17 14] Value1)) = ([52 55 28 17 14] 1)))) endif) <EOF>)
if Value=0  and not Value0=0 and not Value1=1 and not Value2=2 endif
([] ([14] ([17 14] if ([28 17 14] ([12 28 17 14] ([12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value) = ([52 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0)) and ([55 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 28 17 14] Value0)) = ([52 55 12 12 28 17 14] 0))) and ([55 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 28 17 14] Value1)) = ([52 55 12 28 17 14] 1))) and ([55 28 17 14] ([12 55 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 28 17 14] Value2)) = ([52 55 28 17 14] 2)))) endif) <EOF>)
  2    27 msecs   0,2
if Value=0  and not Value0=0 and not Value1=1 and not Value2=2 and not Value3=3 endif
([] ([14] ([17 14] if ([28 17 14] ([12 28 17 14] ([12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value) = ([52 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0)) and ([55 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value0)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0))) and ([55 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 28 17 14] Value1)) = ([52 55 12 12 28 17 14] 1))) and ([55 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 28 17 14] Value2)) = ([52 55 12 28 17 14] 2))) and ([55 28 17 14] ([12 55 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 28 17 14] Value3)) = ([52 55 28 17 14] 3)))) endif) <EOF>)
  3    96 msecs   3,6
if Value=0  and not Value0=0 and not Value1=1 and not Value2=2 and not Value3=3 and not Value4=4 endif
([] ([14] ([17 14] if ([28 17 14] ([12 28 17 14] ([12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value) = ([52 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0)) and ([55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value0)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0))) and ([55 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value1)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] 1))) and ([55 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 28 17 14] Value2)) = ([52 55 12 12 28 17 14] 2))) and ([55 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 28 17 14] Value3)) = ([52 55 12 28 17 14] 3))) and ([55 28 17 14] ([12 55 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 28 17 14] Value4)) = ([52 55 28 17 14] 4)))) endif) <EOF>)
  4    99 msecs   1,0
if Value=0  and not Value0=0 and not Value1=1 and not Value2=2 and not Value3=3 and not Value4=4 and not Value5=5 endif
([] ([14] ([17 14] if ([28 17 14] ([12 28 17 14] ([12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value) = ([52 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0)) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value0)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value1)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 1))) and ([55 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value2)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] 2))) and ([55 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 28 17 14] Value3)) = ([52 55 12 12 28 17 14] 3))) and ([55 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 28 17 14] Value4)) = ([52 55 12 28 17 14] 4))) and ([55 28 17 14] ([12 55 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 28 17 14] Value5)) = ([52 55 28 17 14] 5)))) endif) <EOF>)
  5    65 msecs   0,7
if Value=0  and not Value0=0 and not Value1=1 and not Value2=2 and not Value3=3 and not Value4=4 and not Value5=5 and not Value6=6 endif
([] ([14] ([17 14] if ([28 17 14] ([12 28 17 14] ([12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value) = ([52 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0)) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value0)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value1)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 1))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value2)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 2))) and ([55 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value3)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] 3))) and ([55 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 28 17 14] Value4)) = ([52 55 12 12 28 17 14] 4))) and ([55 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 28 17 14] Value5)) = ([52 55 12 28 17 14] 5))) and ([55 28 17 14] ([12 55 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 28 17 14] Value6)) = ([52 55 28 17 14] 6)))) endif) <EOF>)
  6    90 msecs   1,4
if Value=0  and not Value0=0 and not Value1=1 and not Value2=2 and not Value3=3 and not Value4=4 and not Value5=5 and not Value6=6 and not Value7=7 endif
([] ([14] ([17 14] if ([28 17 14] ([12 28 17 14] ([12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value) = ([52 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0)) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value0)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value1)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 1))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value2)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 2))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value3)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 3))) and ([55 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value4)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] 4))) and ([55 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 28 17 14] Value5)) = ([52 55 12 12 28 17 14] 5))) and ([55 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 28 17 14] Value6)) = ([52 55 12 28 17 14] 6))) and ([55 28 17 14] ([12 55 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 28 17 14] Value7)) = ([52 55 28 17 14] 7)))) endif) <EOF>)
  7   185 msecs   2,1
if Value=0  and not Value0=0 and not Value1=1 and not Value2=2 and not Value3=3 and not Value4=4 and not Value5=5 and not Value6=6 and not Value7=7 and not Value8=8 endif
([] ([14] ([17 14] if ([28 17 14] ([12 28 17 14] ([12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value) = ([52 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0)) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value0)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value1)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 1))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value2)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 2))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value3)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 3))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value4)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 4))) and ([55 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value5)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] 5))) and ([55 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 28 17 14] Value6)) = ([52 55 12 12 28 17 14] 6))) and ([55 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 28 17 14] Value7)) = ([52 55 12 28 17 14] 7))) and ([55 28 17 14] ([12 55 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 28 17 14] Value8)) = ([52 55 28 17 14] 8)))) endif) <EOF>)
  8   358 msecs   1,9
if Value=0  and not Value0=0 and not Value1=1 and not Value2=2 and not Value3=3 and not Value4=4 and not Value5=5 and not Value6=6 and not Value7=7 and not Value8=8 and not Value9=9 endif
([] ([14] ([17 14] if ([28 17 14] ([12 28 17 14] ([12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value) = ([52 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0)) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value0)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value1)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 1))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value2)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 2))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value3)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 3))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value4)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 4))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value5)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 5))) and ([55 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value6)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] 6))) and ([55 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 28 17 14] Value7)) = ([52 55 12 12 28 17 14] 7))) and ([55 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 28 17 14] Value8)) = ([52 55 12 28 17 14] 8))) and ([55 28 17 14] ([12 55 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 28 17 14] Value9)) = ([52 55 28 17 14] 9)))) endif) <EOF>)
  9   837 msecs   2,3
if Value=0  and not Value0=0 and not Value1=1 and not Value2=2 and not Value3=3 and not Value4=4 and not Value5=5 and not Value6=6 and not Value7=7 and not Value8=8 and not Value9=9 and not Value10=10 endif
...
 11  7346 msecs   2,5
if Value=0  and not Value0=0 and not Value1=1 and not Value2=2 and not Value3=3 and not Value4=4 and not Value5=5 and not Value6=6 and not Value7=7 and not Value8=8 and not Value9=9 and not Value10=10 and not Value11=11 and not Value12=12 endif
([] ([14] ([17 14] if ([28 17 14] ([12 28 17 14] ([12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value) = ([52 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0)) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value0)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 0))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value1)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 1))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value2)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 2))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value3)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 3))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value4)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 4))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value5)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 5))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value6)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 6))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value7)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 7))) and ([55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value8)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 12 28 17 14] 8))) and ([55 12 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] Value9)) = ([52 55 12 12 12 28 17 14] 9))) and ([55 12 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 12 28 17 14] Value10)) = ([52 55 12 12 28 17 14] 10))) and ([55 12 28 17 14] ([12 55 12 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 12 28 17 14] Value11)) = ([52 55 12 28 17 14] 11))) and ([55 28 17 14] ([12 55 28 17 14] not ([47 12 55 28 17 14] Value12)) = ([52 55 28 17 14] 12)))) endif) <EOF>)
 12 21790 msecs   3,0
ratio: 2,01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split left-recursive `expr` rule on non-recursive or primitive recursive rules as it described [in my article](http://blog.ptsecurity.com/2016/06/theory-and-practice-of-source-code.html#java--and-java8-grammars).

Answer (score 1):

This is how the grammar looks after the split suggested by @KvanTTT

```
/**
 * see https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/994
 */
grammar primrecexpr;

primrecexpr: if_statement EOF;

if_statement:
  if_part ( else_part ) ? 'endif';

if_part:
  'if' expr statement_list|
  'if' expr;

else_part:
  'else' statement_list |
  'else';

statement_list:
  statement +;  

statement: if_statement; 


expr:
    notexpr
    | expr 'and' expr
    | expr 'or' expr
    ;    

notexpr: 
    'not' notexpr
    | equalexpr;

equalexpr: 
    atomexpr |   
    equalexpr '=' equalexpr
    ;

atomexpr:
   ID
    | VALUE;

VALUE: [0-9]+;
ID: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
WS: [ \t\n\r\f]+ -> skip;
ERROR: .;
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the timing results with the modified grammar

Comment: the result is that there is no measurable impact on performance any more which depends on the length of the expression. Basically the parsing time is always the same and depends on the speed of your computer.